# Can't Locate String in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, string, numpy

I have a DataFrame looking like this (filled with sting dates) and I'm trying to find out the location of a given string. For example '2022-05-29' should be [0,0]

```
        Sunday      Monday      Tuesday     Wednesday   Thursday    Friday      Saturday
June    2022-05-29  2022-05-30  2022-05-31  2022-06-01  2022-06-02  2022-06-03  2022-06-04
June    2022-06-05  2022-06-06  2022-06-07  2022-06-08  2022-06-09  2022-06-10  2022-06-11
June    2022-06-12  2022-06-13  2022-06-14  2022-06-15  2022-06-16  2022-06-17  2022-06-18
June    2022-06-19  2022-06-20  2022-06-21  2022-06-22  2022-06-23  2022-06-24  2022-06-25
July    2022-06-26  2022-06-27  2022-06-28  2022-06-29  2022-06-30  2022-07-01  2022-07-02
```

If I search for '2022-05-29'. Ideally, I should get this:

```
>>> [0,0]
```

I've tried the following methods without any success:

```
grid_table.where([grid_table == '2022-05-29'] == True) 
>>> ValueError: Array conditional must be same shape as self
```

```
[grid_table == '2022-05-29'] == True
>>> False
```

```
grid_table[grid_table == '2022-05-29']
# shows entire grid_table
```

```
grid_table.loc[grid_table == '2022-05-29']
>>> ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: What are the types of these columns? Can you provide the value of `grid_table.dtypes` ?

Comment: @NickODell The columns are pandas.core.indexes.base.Index

Comment: ```grid_table.columns.dtypes >>>AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'dtypes'```

Comment: Just use `numpy.where` ? `np.where(grid_table == '2022-05-29')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

np.where(grid_table == '2022-05-29')